# Consuming Web services in Metro apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-async

i am new to windows 8 metro application development , please let me help out in figuring out this issuse.

i want to consume web services in my metro application but the service reference url is dynamic.

i my app , the user will be given a provision to specify the url in a textbox , so i need to connect to that web service , that means the service reference url will be changing.

Till now i am connecting to web service in a traditional way like , giving a specific service reference by  adding service reference and creating an instance and using that instance  to call all the methods inside that web service .

but,
1) how should i consume web services if the service reference url  is changing.
2)Access individual service methods inside that service (call that methods by passing some parameters as inputs).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this service is some kind of web api ?

Comment: no  , it is the web services which i have developed for consuming in my client application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same service with different locations simply add it with "Add Service Reference..." and add the specified URL in the service client constructor:

```
var svc = new DataServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_DataService", 
    "http://url.com/DataService.svc");
```

`BasicHttpBinding_DataService` is your (generated) binding name from the client config (automatically generated when doing "Add new Web Reference..."):

Example `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig`

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DataService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:44300/Services/DataService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_DataService"
                contract="DataService.DataService" name="BasicHttpBinding_DataService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The code above can be used to change the address (e.g. `https://localhost:44300/Services/DataService.svc`) to one generated at runtime...

And have a look at this: http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=281

Comment: what is  DataServiceClient and BasicHttpBinding_DataService out here ? pls explain

Comment: i dont have the same service name for both , they are different.

Comment: Do you have the same WSDL (same contract) for all web services, only the location (URL) is different?